# How to correctly update partially submitted (to a REST API) objects with LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, rest

Our C# application communicates with a database through a LINQ-to-SQL Database Model, specifically using the MVC4 libraries.

I've been assigned the task of implementing a RESTful API. We thought it would be a good idea to version the API. That way, changes to the API can be introduced in a new version, and existing API clients won't break. To support this, every version of the API has its own set of Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) that it exposes and accepts. Some mapping is done (using AutoMapper) to translate between the API and Database Model.

Currently I'm working on updating and creating functionality. That is, if a client POSTs an `Item` object to the `ItemsController`, and the `Item` does not exist in the database yet (given its unique identifier), a new `Item` should be created. If the identifier is already present in the database, the existing data should be updated. So far so good.

Now, I'm converting a legacy code base to communicate with the RESTful API instead of with the database directly. Some parts of this codebase update a single property on a resource, and send just the identifier and the new value of that single property. The rest of the object should remain as it is in the database.

I'm having trouble implementing this using LINQ-to-SQL, specifically because of the DTO layer. This is the controller method:

```
[HttpPut]
[HttpPost]
public void UpdateOrCreateItem(ItemDTO data)
{
    Item submittedItem = Map(data);
    ItemRepository.UpdateOrCreateItem(submittedItem);
}
```

Now, instead of receiving a fully filled `data` object, only the identifier and one other property are filled. When the LINQ-to-SQL processes this data as follows:

```
public static void UpdateOrCreateItem(Item submittedItem)
{
    if (submittedItem.Id > 0)
    {
        // update
        using (DatabaseAccessor db = new DatabaseAccessor())
        {
            db.context.Items.Attach(submittedItem);
            db.context.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, submittedItem);
            db.context.SubmitChanges();
        }
    } else {
        // create
        // omitted...
    }
}
```

Refreshing marks all the empty (missing) properties as changed, and its all saved to the database. Instead, only the properties that were submitted at the REST API level should be stored. What would be an elegant solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I wrote some code to accept json-patch requests (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902).

- You need to add the media type "application/json-patch" to the collection of accepted formats.
- You need to accept an identifier and an array of JsonPatchOperation objects as input to a HTTP PATCH method on your ApiController

The ApiController method:

```
[HttpPatch]
public void UpdatePartially(int id, JsonPatchOperation[] patchOperations)
{
    if (id > 0)
    {
        // DatabaseAccessor is just a wrapper around my DataContext object
        using (DatabaseAccessor db = new DatabaseAccessor())
        {
            SetDataLoadOptions(db); // optional of course

            var item = db.context.Items.Single(i => i.id == id);

            foreach (JsonPatchOperation patchOperation in patchOperations)
            {
                // when you want to set a foreign key identifier, LINQ-to-SQL throw a ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException
                // the patchOperation will then use GetForeignKeyObject to fetch the object that it requires to set the foreign key object instead
                patchOperation.GetForeignKeyObject = (PropertyInfo property, object identifier) =>
                {
                    // this is just example code, make sure to correct this for the possible properties of your object...
                    if (property == typeof(Item).GetProperty("JobStatus", typeof(JobStatus)))
                    {
                        return db.context.JobStatus.Single(js => js.StatusId == (int)identifier);
                    }
                    else if (property == typeof(Item).GetProperty("User", typeof(User)))
                    {
                        return db.context.Users.Single(u => u.UserId == (Guid)identifier);
                    }

                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("property", String.Format("Missing getter for property '{0}'.", property.Name));
                };

                patchOperation.ApplyTo(item);
            }

            db.context.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

And here are the dependencies of the above method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Add this to the global configuration Formatters collection to accept json-patch requests
/// </summary>
public class JsonPatchMediaTypeFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public JsonPatchMediaTypeFormatter() : base()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json-patch"));
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// All possible values for the "op" property of a json-patch object
/// docs: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-4
/// </summary>
public enum JsonPatchOperationType
{
    add,
    remove,
    replace,
    move,
    copy,
    test
}

/// <summary>
/// json-patch is a partial update format for HTTP PATCH requests
/// docs: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902
/// </summary>
public class JsonPatchOperation
{
    public string op { get; set; }
    public string from { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }

    public Func<PropertyInfo, object, object> GetForeignKeyObject { get; set; }

    public JsonPatchOperationType Operation
    {
        get
        {
            return (JsonPatchOperationType)Enum.Parse(typeof(JsonPatchOperationType), op);
        }
    }

    public void ApplyTo(object document)
    {
        switch (Operation)
        {
            case JsonPatchOperationType.add:
                Add(document, path, value);
                break;
            case JsonPatchOperationType.remove:
                Remove(document, path);
                break;
            case JsonPatchOperationType.replace:
                Replace(document, path, value);
                break;
            case JsonPatchOperationType.move:
                Move(document, path, from);
                break;
            case JsonPatchOperationType.copy:
                Copy(document, path, from);
                break;
            case JsonPatchOperationType.test:
                Test(document, path, value);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void Add(object document, string path, string value)
    {
        Type documentType = document.GetType();
        PathInfo pathInfo = GetPathInfo(documentType, path);
        object convertedValue = ConvertToType(value, pathInfo.PropertyInfo.PropertyType);

        pathInfo.PropertyInfo.SetValue(document, convertedValue, pathInfo.Indexes);
    }

    private void Replace(object document, string path, string value)
    {
        Type documentType = document.GetType();
        PathInfo pathInfo = GetPathInfo(documentType, path);
        object convertedValue = ConvertToType(value, pathInfo.PropertyInfo.PropertyType);

        try
        {
            pathInfo.PropertyInfo.SetValue(document, convertedValue, pathInfo.Indexes);
        }
        // gnarly hack for setting foreign key properties
        catch (TargetInvocationException tie)
        {
            if (tie.InnerException is ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException)
            {
                PropertyInfo matchingProperty = documentType.GetProperties().Single(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssociationAttribute), true).Any(attr => ((AssociationAttribute)attr).ThisKey == pathInfo.PropertyInfo.Name));
                matchingProperty.SetValue(document, GetForeignKeyObject(matchingProperty, convertedValue), null);
            }
            else
            {
                throw tie;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Remove(object document, string path)
    {
        Type documentType = document.GetType();
        PathInfo pathInfo = GetPathInfo(documentType, path);
        pathInfo.PropertyInfo.SetValue(document, GetDefaultValue(pathInfo.PropertyInfo.PropertyType), pathInfo.Indexes);
    }

    private void Copy(object document, string path, string from)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void Move(object document, string path, string from)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void Test(object document, string path, string value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #region Util

    private class PathInfo
    {
        public PropertyInfo PropertyInfo { get; set; }
        public object[] Indexes { get; set; }
    }

    private PathInfo GetPathInfo(Type documentType, string path)
    {
        object[] indexes = null;
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = documentType.GetProperty(path);

        return new PathInfo { PropertyInfo = propertyInfo, Indexes = indexes };
    }

    private object GetDefaultValue(Type t)
    {
        if (t.IsValueType)
            return Activator.CreateInstance(t);

        return null;
    }

    private object ConvertToType(string value, Type type)
    {
        TypeConverter typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type);
        return typeConverter.ConvertFromString(value);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

It should be obvious that this is not finished, mature or elegant. But it works.